# Which dates came first across adjacent columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns with a 2 long lists of dates. Is there a formula i can use in a third column to determine which date came earlier across each row, that is better then manually comparing across each rows

Thanks

EvR

Answer (score 2):

Format the new column as date:

```
=IF(A2<B2,A2,B2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MIN` function

```
=MIN(A2:B2)
```